# Ruby: How do I get out of this loop

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
line = gets
while line = gets
   print line
end
puts 'out of loop'
```

How do I make line `return nil`?

Please note that on the second line `line=gets` is on purpose, so when `gets=nil`, `line=nil` and the whole condition becomes false.

Comment: Are you waiting for an empty line, then? This should work fine when your input is EOF-terminated.

Comment: How would you like it to exit the loop? You can have the user enter a special string or whatever.

Comment: what is the condition to exit from the loop? a special character? you should put the `line = gets` inside while loop instead of condition

Comment: Unless you are intentionally skipping the first line of input you should remove your first `line = gets`.  The loop will terminate when there is no more input (if you're redirecting STDIN) or when you type `Ctrl-d` (*nix/Mac) or `Ctrl-z` (Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "As somebody giving input from the command line, how would I make this terminate?": You would hit ctrl-D.

If you mean "How can I exit this loop programmatically?": Just check for whatever condition would terminate the loop and if it is true then `break`.

Answer (score 3):

`gets` returns `nil` when it gets `EOF` (End of File).

You can send your terminal an `EOF`, this is done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on a Unix-like system. or <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> on Windows.

Reference: [IO#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-gets)